# Conversion of Windows.Graphics.Capture.Direct3D11CaptureFrame to OpenCvSharp::Mat

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, windows-runtime, directx

As the title suggests, the aim is to convert `Direct3DCaptureFrame` from the `Windows.Graphics.Capture` API to a matrix object available in OpenCvSharp (`Mat`) so that the captured frame may be used with the popular Computer Vision Library.

There's an in-depth issue available [on GitHub](https://github.com/TheBlackPlague/DynoSharp/issues/2) which gives reference to current attempts and findings. It also includes sample of what the result should look like and what it does as of now.

I personally believe my way isn't the right way and there may be an easier way to handle this, but I just decided to map the memory and copy it to a `byte[]`. `OpenCvSharp::Mat` has constructor overloads which allow one to reference data.

If there is a better (hopefully as performant) and easy way to do this, please do suggest it. I would love some help here.

Comment: byte[] or IntPtr ctor are probably the only usable ones. I would prefer IntPtr since it should not require any .NET allocation (only pointer passing). The other solution would be to present the result of WinRT Capture as a virtual camera that you could capture with OpenCV, but that's complicated.

Comment: You can check the current implementation using the GitHub link in the post: it's using `byte[]` for the `OpenCvSharp::Mat`. Unsure if there's a better way, which is why I ask. It's also not working properly so if you suggest changes, would love that. Can also PR. :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was recently fixed by myself.

The missing thing was padding when referencing the `byte[]`. It is required to set the `step` parameter of `Mat`'s overloaded constructor to `width * (bytes / pixel)`. In my case, `bytes / pixel` was `4`.